# jQuery - cat is not defined - can't work it out

Tags: javascript, jquery

The below script is giving the error - ReferenceError: cat is not defined.
I'm missing something simple I know!

```
// calculate the sum of each table
$(calculateSum);

function calculateSum() {
    var sum = 0;
    // iterate through each td based on class and add the values
    $.each(['income', 'expenses', 'bills', 'savings', 'debt'], function(index, cat) {

        var value = $('#'+cat+' .amount').text();
        // add only if the value is number
        if(!isNaN(value) && value.length != 0) {
            sum += parseFloat(value);
        }
    });
$('#'+cat+' .total').text('$'+ sum); 
};
```

Comment: is cat declared anywhere within the scope your trying to use it?....

Comment: `cat` is not defined in teh scope of `calculateSum` it is available only inside the `each` callback

Comment: $('#'+cat+' .total').text('$'+ sum); Can't find cat outside the $.each loop.

Comment: can you share the target html

Answer (score 2):

`cat` is the argument to the function you're passing into `$.each`, so it doesn't exist outside that function. Either you need to move the `$('#'+cat+' .total').text('$'+ sum);` line *into* the function, or do something else entirely.

---

Note that your code combines the values for various different categories (income, expenses, etc.) in a *single* `sum` variable. The whole logic of the code shown looks a bit suspect, you may want to step back and look at it in the broader context of what you're trying to do.

Comment: I understand what you mean. Just not sure how to implement it

Answer (score 0):

Move this

```
$('#'+cat+' .total').text('$'+ sum);
```

iniside

```
$.each()
```